# How to center text in a background div baloon image?

Tags: html, css

I am having a difficulty on how to center a text in a div with background image. This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/VnqeY/12/

Thank you.

Comment: That code would be much less jumbled if you used an external stylesheet or put stuff in the `<style>` tag.

Comment: @Mahnax True, did it http://jsfiddle.net/VnqeY/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VnqeY/16/

Read up on CSS relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnqeY/18/)

Just declare `line-height` and set the `<a>` to be `vertical-align: middle`

```
.balloon{
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/B19Zb.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.1em;
    height:140px;
    width:140px;
    line-height: 118px;  
}
.balloon a{
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:yellow;
    text-align:center
}

<div class="balloon">
    <a href="#">Advertise with us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

one option is to you `display:table-cell`  The image and size and such needs fixed though.